opencv CMAKE BUILD error at very end...is this error important?
Is this error a problem or not really?
When I check the directory, the file is there.
Seems like this is some issue of timing... the cmake DOES write the directory... yet this error says its not there.
How can I fix this cmake error?  Or is this nothing to worry about?
>     -- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/videostab/wobble_suppression.hpp
>     -- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/opencv4/samples/videostab/videostab.cpp
>     -- Up-to-date: /usr/local/share/opencv4/samples/videostab
>     -- Up-to-date: /root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py
>     -- Up-to-date: /root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/load_config_py2.py
>     -- Up-to-date: /root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/load_config_py3.py
>     -- Installing: /root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/config.py
>     -- Up-to-date: /root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/misc/__init__.py
>     -- Up-to-date: /root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/misc/version.py
>     -- Up-to-date: /root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/mat_wrapper/__init__.py
>     -- Up-to-date: /root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/utils/__init__.py
>     -- Up-to-date: /root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/gapi/__init__.py
> 
>     -- Installing: ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2 CMake Error at modules/python3/cmake_install.cmake:162 (file):    file
> INSTALL cannot set permissions on   
> "~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2":  No such file or
> directory.  Call Stack (most recent call first):   
> cmake_install.cmake:290 (include)
>     
>     
>     make: *** [Makefile:130: install] Error 1
> 
> sd@ASUS:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2$ l total
> 63M drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 aruco drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd
> 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 barcode
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd  724 Apr 28 06:45 config-3.py
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd  111 Apr 28 06:45 config.py drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 cuda
> -rwxrwxr-x  1 sd sd  63M Apr 28 06:45 cv2.abi3.so drwxrwxr-x  3 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 data drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 detail drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 dnn drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr
> 28 06:45 Error drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 fisheye
> drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 flann drwxrwxr-x 15 sd sd 4.0K
> Apr 28 06:45 gapi
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd 6.5K Apr 28 06:45 __init__.py
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd 287K Apr 28 06:45 __init__.pyi drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 ipp
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd 148K Apr 28 06:45 LICENSE-3RD-PARTY.txt
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd 1.1K Apr 28 06:45 LICENSE.txt
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd  151 Apr 28 06:45 load_config_py2.py
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd  262 Apr 28 06:45 load_config_py3.py drwxrwxr-x  3 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 mat_wrapper drwxrwxr-x  3 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28
> 06:45 misc drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 ml drwxrwxr-x  2 sd
> sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 ocl drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 ogl
> drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 parallel drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd
> 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 __pycache__
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd    0 Apr 28 06:45 py.typed drwxrwxr-x  4 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 qt drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 samples drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 segmentation drwxrwxr-x  3 sd sd
> 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 typing drwxrwxr-x  5 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 utils
> -rw-rw-r--  1 sd sd   92 Apr 28 06:45 version.py drwxrwxr-x  2 sd sd 4.0K Apr 28 06:45 videoio_registry


Please, don't post images of text (let alone ones with such garish colours).

No problem. What you should do now, is [edit] your post and replace that image with the actual text ;)

Photo of TEXT has been removed, replaced with actual text.  Thanks for the feedback and suggestion.

/root/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2 vs ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2 | And then you have sd@ASUS:~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2$ where both the part before @ and the $ of the prompt suggest you're not root at that point. What's going on? Seems like there are two different user directories  with virtualenvs at play...
